# Linking a json file with events to fullcalendar

Tags: json, fullcalendar

I have a json file with specified events in there. The basic code which calls calendar is this. I can list the events from within the calendar itself but they want it as a json file so that events can be changed on the fly without touching anything else. I tried several appproach but it did not work well.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
            defaultDate: '2015-02-12',
            selectable: true,
            selectHelper: true,
            select: function(start, end) {
                var title = prompt('Event Title:');
                var eventData;
                if (title) {
                    eventData = {
                        title: title,
                        start: start,
                        end: end
                    };
                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', eventData, true); // stick? = true
                }
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');
            },
        editable: true,
        eventLimit: true,
```

Comment: You should just update your [original question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28949779/fullcalendar-using-a-server-json-file). It appears this is the same issue.

Comment: you will have to use some server side scripting language to read the file and return back the result this will help.